# Problema para mostrar datos en toolstripcombobox

Tags: c#, windows-forms

tengo varios toostripcombobox que lleno directamente desde la BD con una lista de objetos que he creado.
He configurado el `ValueMember` y `DisplayMember` pero no muestra el "Display" correcto, en su lugar el nombre del Objeto que representa **(models.MiObjeto)**, es decir, en lugar de que se vean los nombres de los objetos p/e: Casa, Perro, Bolsa; muestra la leyenda `models.MiObjeto`

Este es mi código:

```
List<MiObjeto> lista = controlador.ObtenerDatos();

toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = 
  toolStripComboBox2.ComboBox.DataSource = lista;

toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DisplayMember = 
  toolStripComboBox2.ComboBox.DisplayMember = "Nombre";

toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.ValueMember = 
  toolStripComboBox2.ComboBox.ValueMember = "IdObjeto";
```

El objeto MiObjeto es así:

```
public class MiObjeto
{
    public String IdObjeto{ get; set; }
    public String Nombre { get; set; }
    public String Responsable { get; set; }
    public String IdActividad{ get; set; }
    public String Status { get; set; }
}
```

Esta es la función ObtenerDatos():

```csharp
public List<MiObjeto> ObtenerDatos()
{
    return _com.DB.Query("tableName")
            .Get<MiObjeto>().ToList();
}
```

Alguien sabe que puede ser?, he intentado también configurando el *BindingContext*, pero nada :(

Comment: Cual es el código de tu función ObtenerDatos

Comment: Prueba primero poniendo el valuemember, después el displaymember y por último el datasource

Comment: No, no funcionó sigue mostrándose como lo describí, en cuanto a la función ObtenerDatos regresa literal un List<MiObjeto>

Comment: Tu codigo dice exactamente toolStripComboBox1.ComboBox.DataSource = 
  toolStripComboBox2.ComboBox.DataSource = lista;??? con dos iguales?

Comment: Así es, ya los separé de igual forma pero aun sigo sin poder